# Error while loading shared libraries: libpgplot.so:

Tags: makefile, plot

I have compiled a program named vmed from its source code using Makefile. When I run make the compilation goes without any error, however when I try to run the program, it gives me following error:

```
./vmed: error while loading shared libraries: libpgplot.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have pgplot plot already installed. Also following libX11.so packages are installed on my ubuntu 1904:

```
shah@shah-VBox:~$ apt-file search libX11.so
libx11-6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
libx11-6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
libx11-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
nxagent: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nx/X11/libX11.so.6
nxagent: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nx/X11/libX11.so.6.3.0
```

Can anyone point me in right direction and point what I am doing wrong. Following is the make file for the program.

```
#
# Makefile for vmed
#
EXEDIR=/usr/local/vmed/
#EXEDIR=/mn/vann/it-scratch/gfprog/VMED/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#
FC = gfortran
CFLAGS = -O 
FFLAGS = -O4 -ffixed-line-length-132
X11LIB = -lX11
#PGLIB =  -L/mn/geologi/gfgruppe-prog/PGPLOT -lpgplot
UCBLIB = 
LIB = -L/usr/lib -lpng
PGLIB =  -L/usr/local/pgplot  -lpgplot
LDLIBS = $(PGLIB) $(X11LIB) $(UCBLIB) $(LIB) -lm
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Source objects. If your compiler cannot find the functions
# "date_and_time" and "lnblnk", then add datetime.o and lnblnk.o
# to the list of objects below.
#
VMED_OBJS= main.o getvpar.o vmed_axis.o vmed_plotmod.o \
           vmed_util.o vmed_colorize.o vmed_vcontrast.o vmed_lvz.o \
           vmed_cursor.o vmed_twtt.o vmed_1d.o chleng.o \
           vmed_buttons.o vmed_help.o \
           vmed_cursubs.o vmed_butsubs.o plot.o ri2grid.o \
           contour.o vmed_edit.o vmed_editsubs.o writeriv.o
#
# Executable name
#
VMED_EXEC=$(EXEDIR)vmed
#
all: main
main: $(VMED_OBJS)
    $(FC) -o main ${VMED_OBJS} -lX11 $(LDLIBS)
    mv main ${VMED_EXEC}

# dependencies
#
contour.o          :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
getvpar.o          :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
main.o             :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
ri2grid.o          :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_1d.o          :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_butsubs.o     :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_colorize.o    :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_cursor.o      :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_cursubs.o     :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_edit.o        :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_editsubs.o    :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_lvz.o         :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_plotmod.o     :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_twtt.o        :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_util.o        :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
vmed_vcontrast.o   :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
writeriv.o         :  rayinvr.par rayinvr.com
```

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing to give more info. Is it [this vmed](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/users/bzelt/vmed/vmed.html)? How did you get the source code? Did you modify the makefile? If so, how? Also, how and (if you know) where did you install pgplot? Did you install the `pgplot5` package? If not, why not, and could you use that? If you installed it from source, had you run `sudo ldconfig`? If not, does that help? What's the output of `lsb_release -a`, `uname -a`, `apt list pgplot5`, `file /usr/lib/pgplot.so`, and (in the directory with the compiled `vmed` executable) `file vmed` and `ldd vmed`?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed PGPLOT before on my Ubuntu Machines without much problem. Be sure you have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to where `libpgplot.so` is.